# R Wrong logical subsetting for a vector

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have two logical vectors.

```
a <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

When I try to subset b to a like this

```
b[which(a == 1)]
```

everything is as I expect. However, like this

```
b[a]
```

I get different result.

Why? Probably the explanation is obvious but I completely don't understand...

Comment: You don't have logical vectors. They clearly and obviously are numeric.

Comment: @Roland ok. Do you have an answer to my question though?

Comment: Yes, but Henrik already told you where to find your answer. His advice is good. Every R user should have studied that documentation and reread it regularly. I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is a binary vector.  It can be converted to boolean with `as.logical` and then it will work as expected i.e. it will get the elements in 'b' that corresponds to TRUE values in 'a'

```
b[as.logical(a)]
```

because 0 is considered as FALSE whereas all other values can be TRUE

```
as.logical(c(1, 0, 2, 3))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Otherwise, indexing starts in `R` from 1 and the 1 value is selecting the first element based on the position, where as `which(a == 1)`, gets the position of sequence from logical vector

---

```
b[c(1, 1, 0, 1)]
```

selects the first element of 'b' three times

whereas

```
b[which(c(1, 1, 0, 1) == 1)]
```

gets the position as 1, 2, 4 for selecting the 'b'

```
which(c(1, 1, 0, 1) == 1)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I am still a bit confused but I'll re-read, do some experiments and hopefully understand!

Comment: @AnnaPlaxienko Once you convert to logical `== 1`, there is no need for `which` (assuming there are no `NAs`) beacuse it selects only elements that correspond to TRUE ie.. whereever the 1 is present.  Because the indexing also works with numeric values 1, 0 is considered as integer/numeric.  So, the position is always 1 for whereever 1 is present, while 0 is dropped as there is no 0 index in R

Comment: @AnnaPlaxienko Please let me know about the confusion part.  I will try to give some example so that it becomes clear to you.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @akrun explained, you need logical values for subseting `b` based on `a`.

Below is another option to turn numeric `a` to a logical one, e.g.,

```
> b[!!a]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[39] 1 0 0 0
```